# How do I produce a heap dump with only a JRE?

Tags: java, heap-dump

We have a JRE installed on our production environment, but not a JDK. The versions of the JRE and OS are below.

```
[me@mymachine ~]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
[me@mymachine ~]$ uname -a
Linux mymachine.mydomain.com 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 2 09:36:59 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It doesn’t appear as if the `jmap` tool is present anywhere on the system, and without root access, I’m not in a position to install it in any system location.  What can I do to get a heap dump (i.e. produce a `.hprof` file)?

Also, we're using JBoss 7.1.3.AS if that matters.

Comment: I think you need JDK, let us wait and see if anyone has other solution.

Comment: Beginning with jre 7, oracle provides a server-jre assembly which includes these tools.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html

Comment: Good to know.  Unfrotunately upgrading our JRE is not an option at this time.

Comment: are you able to connect to your production environment through a JMX port?

Answer (score 17):

Use [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach), a tool created by JVM hacker Andrei Pangin. It's tiny (24KB), works with just JRE and supports Linux containers.

`jattach PID-OF-JAVA dumpheap <path to heap dump file>`

Comment: This is a great idea. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

Built-in tools like `jmap`, `jconsole`, and `jvisualvm` are only available in a JDK. Another option is to add the VM argument `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` which tells the JVM to automatically generate a heap dump when an OutOfMemoryError occurs, and the argument `-XX:HeapDumpPath` to specify the path for the heap dump.

If you cannot upgrade your JRE to use tools like the ones in the server JRE 7 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html), you may have to consider third-party profiling tools like [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or ones list [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers).

Comment: I'm open to other tools other than jmap that can produce a heap dump.  The thing is I would have to be able to run it from my home directory.

Comment: Maybe a third-party profiler would be useful here. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way seems to be to zip your local SDK6 and put it somewhere on the server. Then open a remote console and from within the bin directory of that SDK dump the JRE.

If your client forbids uploading executable files, you are out of luck of course.